# grep match pattern and save to different file

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have some lines in an mpd file as mentioned below. I want to grep only the words ending with `.ts` and save them in a different file. Can someone help me on that?

```
    <SegmentURL media="1.ts" mediaRange="0-3424419"/>
 <SegmentURL media="2.ts" mediaRange="0-8063319"/>
 <SegmentURL media="3.ts" mediaRange="0-7146631"/>
 <SegmentURL media="4.ts" mediaRange="0-8984143"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -o '\<\w*\.ts\>' infile
1.ts
2.ts
3.ts
4.ts
```

- `\<` and `\>` are beginning/end of word markers
- `\w` is a synonym for `[_[:alnum:]]` (just `[[:alnum:]]` in BSD grep)
- `-o` retains only the matches

To save the output to a file `output`, redirect with `> output` appended to the command.

Answer (score 0):

For given example, you don't need the PCRE, BRE is sufficient for your needs.

```
grep -o '[^"][.]ts' file
```

But keep in mind that grep does line-based match. If your input file is html/xml, particularly, if it was generated by some application, the lines could be broken. Thus, grep may fail.

Using a xml/html parser if that was the case.